# Critical points of the function $f(x,y) = xe^y$ subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2=2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

To find critical points of the function $f(x,y) = xe^y$ subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2=2$.

Let $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-2$. We use the method of Lagrange Multipliers:

$$f_x = \lambda g_x \implies e^y = 2\lambda x , f_y = \lambda g_y \implies xe^y = 2\lambda y.$$

From the above, we get $x^2 = y$ and using $x^2+y^2=2$ we have $y = 1,-2$. Thus the critical point is $(1,1)$.

Is the answer and method correct?

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, when you say that $x^2 = y$, you are assuming that $\lambda \ne 0$. You should also cover this case. Even if you can immediately dismiss it, it should be mentioned. Also, you seem to be missing critical points... Why is $(-1,1)$ not a critical point?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the other critical point. Once you get $y=1$, you get $x^2=1$, $x=\pm 1$, so the critical points are $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$.